# Getting date in shell script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, datetime

I have a requirement to grep a particular pattern from the last few days' log files.

I am trying to get the past few days date into a variable which can be substituted in the grep command for searching the pattern. The log pattern is as below:

```
log-gr_base.log.2017-06-08.gz
```

However, I am getting the error as below

```
date: invalid date ‘=1 day ago’
date: invalid date ‘=2 day ago’
date: invalid date ‘=3 day ago’
date: invalid date ‘=4 day ago’
```

Shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
for ((dy=1;dy<=4;dy++))
do
dt= $(date --date ="$dy day ago" +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo $dt
done
```

**Expected results are**

```
2017-06-11
2017-06-10
2017-06-09
2017-06-08
```

Comment: You should not have a space between `--date` and `="$dy day ago"`. Also, you have some other syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

few changes:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((dy=1;dy<=4;dy++))
do
    dt=$(date --date="$dy days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    echo $dt
done
```

with `/bin/sh` (for me is `dash`) and in `dash` c like for format does not work so do:

```
#!/bin/sh
for dy in `seq 1 4`
do
    dt=$(date --date="$dy days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    echo $dt
done
```